# Clear phpcodesniffer markings in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, phpcodesniffer

Phpcodesniffer has added a lot of markings to my source file based in the PSR1, PSR2 standards. Many of them are related to code formatting like tags and spaces.

I want to clear the current markings and run codesniffer later on in my development, not at this current stage.

My searches did not yield any results.

I posted an example of my editor screen below.

How can I clear the markings.

[image: PHPCodeSniffer markings in eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this in the following way.

1. Open the 'Problems' tab at the bottom of the screen. if it is not available, you can access it from the Window -> Show View -> Other -> Problem menu option.
2. Choose the problems you want to delete (in my case, all)
3. Chose Delete